# PDB file crashdump user.dmp

Tags: windows, crash, windbg, pdb-files

I have an application crash, and as a result it is generating a crash dump in Windows platform. I send the exe and dll file to the customer. The customer has sent the user.dmp and drwtsn32.log file me. But, the customer do not have the corresponding pdb file. The customer just has dll and exe file. So, when I attach this user.dmp file to Windbg, I do not get the symbols. So, what do I need to do to get the symbols. Do, I need to send the pdb files to the customer? If yes, what he needs to do with these pdb file when a crash happens? 
I use three different machines: a) the build machine, c) the customer's test machine and c) my own debugging machine (not same as the build machine). 
The windbg is installed in the debugging machine. I can copy all the pdb files into my debugging machine from the build machine. 
Please let me know, how the customer can make use of the pdb files and how I do the debugging later.

Thanks
Kongkon

Answer (score 4):

If you have the correct PDB files for the executables, you just need to point WinDbg to the correct path when debugging the dump. Use the symbol path feature for this.

Additional info in this question: [debug symbol issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665003/debug-symbol-issue)

Answer (score 3):

The great thing about gathering DMP files is that the customer doesn't need PDB files at the time of creating the DMP file.   You only need pdbs when you debug into the DMP file!

Comment: Hi, How do I get or generate the DMP file?

Comment: The easiest way I found is to use the microsoft tool 'userdump'.  Check out this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241215

Comment: Also if on Vista or higher you can right-click the process in task manager and choose 'create dump file'

Comment: If the Windows Error Reporting service is running then DMP files automatically show up in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\CrashDumps\` (at least I've only tried this on Win7).